# Loading thumbnail images depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to load a number of thumbnail images on to a page depending on the width of the page. The number of images loaded will depend on the width of the page.

The images (100 x 100) will load such that they're side by side and they take up the entire width of the screen.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

This is what I have come up with so far: -

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    #dv_frame {
        width: 100%;
        /*border: 1px solid #cccccc;*/
        text-align: center;
        height: 110px;
        position: relative;

    }

    #dv_images {
        /*border: solid 1px blue;*/
        height: 100px;

        margin: auto;

    }

    .myImage{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: solid 1px red;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }



</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var container = $("#dv_frame")
        var tWidth = 0
        var width = container.width()

        for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {
            tWidth = tWidth + 110
            if (tWidth > (width - 10)) {
                $("#dv_images").css("width", (tWidth - 80))
                break;
            }
            addSquare()
        }

        function addSquare() {
            $("#dv_images").append("<div class='myImage'></div>")
        }

    });

</script>

   </head>

 <body>
<div id="dv_frame"><div id="dv_images"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get the width of the window, divide by 100, and you have the number of images you need to request. I'm sure if you provide some code people will be happy to help you along, but seems like you just want someone to write this for you?

Comment: Fair enough, I've entered what I have so far. I just wondered if there was a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding images, and checking the width each time, I would just calculate the number of images you need from the start. Add them to a dummy div which isn't in the DOM, then finally append that to your container (for speed & efficiency).

```
var $container = $("#dv_frame"),
    imageWidth = 110, // including margin & padding
    imagesNeeded = Math.floor($container.width() / imageWidth), // rounded down, width/imageWidth
    i, // iterator
    $foo = $('<div></div>'); // empty container div

for(i = 0; i < imagesNeeded; i++) {
    // appending to our empty container div
    $foo.append("<div class='myImage'></div>");
}

// then appending the contents of our container div to the DOM.
// this is quicker and more efficient than doing lots of appends to the DOM in a loop.
$("#dv_images").append($foo.contents());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/d8WNy/